# Binding Element and it's properties. MVC & WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-binding, configuration-files

I'm working on a project which includes a file uploader, now after extensive research and experimentation the uploader is working. However, it makes me uneasy as I don't understand the part that got it working the way I wanted it to. In order to achieve my goal I had to add a binding element to the service and the client (n-tier application) I don't really understand the binding element to tell you the truth, but I really don't understand the parameters in this element. If anyone is able, please provide a source where I can read up on these specific elements and if possible, describe them yourself.

Here is the section of code:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUploadService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="8388608"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        allowCookies="false">

        <readerQuotas 
            maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
            maxArrayLength="8388608" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
            maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

</binding>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found exactly what I was looking for after wording my google search appropriately

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding_properties(v=vs.85).aspx